# Can screenshot's be disabled in an android app?

Tags: android

I am curious to know if screenshots can be disabled when running a android app if I were to design one.

Comment: why would you want to? If you don't want your app's display to be captured, what's to stop someone from using ANOTHER camera to take a picture of their screen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764568/prevent-screen-capture-in-android-apps

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to [use `FLAG_SECURE` to block screenshots and thumbnails of your activities](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html):

```
public class FlagSecureTestActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                         LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```