# Disbaled Website Screenshot in mobile

Tags: mobile, screenshot

please anyone can help me to disabled screenshots in mobile for my website. which works on android and IO's with any browser?

Comment: You can't stop people from taking screenshots on their own phone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way of disabling screenshots in a website, for android or IOS, how ever you can refer to [Prevent screen capture in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app), for information on how to do it in an app, The most prominent way of doing such would by doing a Snapchat deal, You could get could create a notification code to your email, and from that find people that screenshot it. But there is no way to completely disable the ability to screenshot.