# Xamarin Forms: Prevent screenshot in ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library

HI I am developing an app using Xamarin Forms PCL project. I want to restrict user from taking screenshot in my ios app . How can I prevent user from taking screenshot?

Comment: I doubt this problem is solvable in all cases. Even if you could do that in-app, one could still mirror screen to his TV and take screenshot there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't prevent screenshots, using xamarin won't change anything about this. But you can detect them (like snapchat does) [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app).

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible** to prevent user from taking screenshots in iOS (as far as I know), **currently**. The operating system itself only can restrict users from taking screenshots, currently (also).

Still you can do something to make the process of taking screenshots **harder**. Users need to press the sleep/wake button and the home button in order to take screenshots and it needs both hands. So you can implement a way to show the data only when the user touches someplace in the screen. Such a mechanism would be great in this case.

Comment: "But Apple will someday allow Xamarin iOS developers to prevent screenshots" where did you get this information from?

Comment: We've been talking about Screenshot a long ago in many forums, It's kind of a rumor or something. It could be fake by the way. But who cares?

Comment: Probably people who want to implement this? haha Please stick to facts or at least mark uncertain information as a rumor when posting answers, this isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: I didn't mean to destroy anyone's answer with that.

Comment: I know you didn't mean any harm, but answers should always be fact driven ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm a noobie, as you can guess with my reputation :)