# How to restrict taking screenshot in iOS app programmatically?

Tags: objective-c

I want to avoid taking screenshot or disable screen capture in my app for security reason in objective c.

Is it possible to prevent screenshot in iOS app?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app

Comment: I already tried but its not working in my app .

Comment: Please consider that a photo of the screen can always be taken by another device. Preventing screen capture for security reasons makes little sense.

Comment: but it would be a way of protecting against malware attacks:
https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/US-13-Lau-Mactans-Injecting-Malware-into-iOS-Devices-via-Malicious-Chargers-WP.pdf