# Is there any way to disable or detect screen recording in movie playing view for iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, screen-recording

Can you suggest any idea to prevent screen recording as user make copy of my content by screen recording.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIScreen.isCaptured` property *is* the recommended way of doing this by Apple. See the following article:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1970/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017687

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so Its possible because still apple officially does not announce that we can do like that but as I know that in iOS 11  `UIScreen` has new property [`isCaptured`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921651-iscaptured)

> True if this screen is being captured.

You can do something by use of it. But not sure that you can prevent screen recording.

Second below question might be helpful for you.

[Prevent screen capture in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app)