# Detect iPhone power button down event to prevent screen shot in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working on the feature to prevent ScreenShot taken from my application. We can achieve this by Configuration Profile which available on Enterprise Developer Account. The thing is i want to do it in Developer Account. So i'm tried below techniques

1. Observing the **UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification** notification. But it was triggered after the screen shot taken.
2. Tried to use a **touchesCancelled:** method. From iOS7 onwards  **touchesCancelled:** is not called during screenshot taken.
3. When i'm looking on device log, the below outputs was logged.

   Mar 14 13:05:58 iPod backboardd[58] : Lock usagePage:0xc usage:0x30 downEvent:1 down
   Mar 14 13:05:58 iPod SpringBoard[53] : canceling volume button presses
   Mar 14 13:05:59 iPod backboardd[58] : Home usagePage:0xc usage:0x40 downEvent:0 up
   Mar 14 13:05:59 iPod SpringBoard[53] : Take screenshot: 3
   Mar 14 13:05:59 iPod ScreenShot[4689] : Name 
    :::_UIWindowSystemGestureStateChangedNotification
   Mar 14 13:05:59 iPod backboardd[58] : Lock usagePage:0xc usage:0x30 downEvent:0 up
   Mar 14 13:05:59 iPod backboardd[58] : Home usagePage:0xc usage:0x40 downEvent:0 phase:0x4 timeout
   Mar 14 13:05:59 iPod SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[53] : [FBSystemService][0x7bd4] Received request to open "com.apple.ScreenshotServicesService" from SpringBoard:53.
   Mar 14 13:05:59 iPod SpringBoard[53] : sending screenshot action to scene: 
   Mar 14 13:05:59 iPod SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[53] : [FBSystemService][0x5ca0] Received request to open "com.apple.ScreenshotServicesService" from SpringBoard:53.
   Mar 14 13:05:59 iPod SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[53] : [FBSystemService] Trusting entitled client .

**3.1** Tried to trace the device logs using **ASL**. This is also deprecated.

**3.2** Tried to access the system processes using **sysctl()**. This is also deprecated

**3.3** Tried to access the iPhones Private Frameworks to Swizzle the methods on it. But no luck i can't find correct method to swizzle. I know this is not recommended just i'd tried.

Is there any solutions to obtain this case before screen shot is taken, so that i'll change the Application UI.

Thanks.,

Comment: Have you reviewed [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+prevent+screenshot)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent screen capture in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://screenshieldkit.com, I think they have what you need and by using **UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification** you could also notify other users that a screenShot was taken

Comment: How does this help? The `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification` tells your app that the user has already taken a screen shot. It doesn't let your prevent anything. Any why notify the user that a screen shot was taken? They know they just took one.

Comment: For exemple if you have a chat app , you could notify the other user that a screenshot was taken, that is what I meant by notifying the user, I think (I'm not sure) that this behaviour is already implemented on apps like instagram or snapchat

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The only publicly available API is to know that **a screenshot is already taken**, but it doesn't allow to prevent it (it informs **after** the screenshot was made).

Yes, on older iOS versions it used to be possible to surpass this restriction, but on newer iOS versions this is not possible yet (at least not without jailbreaking).

Anyway, that's a native option given by iOS, so blocking it would lead to app rejection in the App Store anyway. You should implement other techniques like Instagram Stories and stuff like that do: they inform the publisher of the content that a screenshot was taken.

Answer (score 0):

SUPPORTED IOS 17 AND BELOW VERSIONS

I worked on an app where securing chat content was a requirement. After R&D, I concluded that preventing screen capture in an iOS app is not directly supported by the iOS operating system. However, we can customize our code to achieve the desired result.

As a solution, I created [ScreenShield](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield), an iOS library designed to secure content by blocking screenshots and screen recordings. It provides a simple solution to protect your app's content. I hope it proves helpful for others facing the same challenge.

[ScreenShield for ios UIKit/SwiftUI](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield)

HOW TO USE:

Add the following line to your Podfile and run pod install:

```
pod 'ScreenShield'
```

UIKIT EXAMPLE:

```
import UIKit
import ScreenShield

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        
        // Protect ScreenShot
        ScreenShield.shared.protect(view: self.view)
        
        // Protect Screen-Recording
        ScreenShield.shared.protectFromScreenRecording()
    }
}
```

SWIFTUI EXAMPLE:

```
import SwiftUI
import ScreenShield

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .protectScreenshot() // Protect the view
            .onAppear {
                ScreenShield.shared.protectFromScreenRecording() // Protect Screen-Recording
            }
    }
}
```