# Disable screenshot capture for Flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter

I am making a Flutter app and I need to make sure the user is not able to capture screenshot of the app (any screen). Is there any way to achieve this in Flutter or do I need to write native code for both Android and iOS?

Comment: Is that even possible at all?

Comment: I don't know, thats why I am asking here.

Comment: In flutter it's currently unavailable, but you can write native code for Android & iOS as you said and maybe create a request on the GitHub of flutter ;)

Comment: If it is possible natively in Android and iOS, it should be possible in Flutter by writing a plugin or using channels. But first you must be sure it can be done natively.

Comment: Relevant URL: [FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE)

Comment: @chemamolins It is possible in Native Android and iOS

Comment: @codeinprogress It's works for me. You can try my answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72283925/9331686

Answer (score 48):

It's only in **iOS**, just modify in AppDelegate.
And no more plugins

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    self.window.makeSecure() //Add this line 
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

}
//And this extension
extension UIWindow {
func makeSecure() {
    let field = UITextField()
    field.isSecureTextEntry = true
    self.addSubview(field)
    field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
    field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.layer)
  }
}
```

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IOkU.png)

Comment: This answer works I've tested it, and deserves more votes!

Comment: @ClarkCluster, why did you copied and pasted my answer?

Comment: NOTE: you should change value of `isSecureTextEntry` in app lifecycle methods as I did in my answer. Otherwise you will get side effect: "red screen". Actions: go to background, switch to another app and back to your app (preview of your app will be red).

Comment: Yes sir, it just not work in my case, I figure out in my way as ur code really help me a lot, also I don't know should changed lifecycle methods, thanks for tips sir.

Comment: This makes a screenshot whole black screen on iOS. Great!

Comment: Can someone explain the last 2 lines, please?

Comment: Does it work on simulator? I implemented this code on a new created flutter project and ran on a simulator. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Only on real iOS device

Comment: i test on real device its not working ios 12.5 version

Comment: in 2023 May, it works as well, thanks. Still a valid answer.

Comment: IMP NOTE: THIS IS THE INCORRECT WAY TO HANDLE THE PREVENTING THE SCREENSHOT. APPLE IS REJECTING A APP THAT USES THIS TECHNIQUE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75181008/flutter-ios-prevent-screenshot#:~:text=takes%20a%20screenshot.-,Duplicating%20system%2Dprovided%20interfaces%20does%20not%20provide%20the%20simple%2C%20innovative,provided%20screenshot%20interface%20and%20functionality.%22      CHECK THIS LINK FOR MORE CLARIFICATION. EVEN MY APP IS ALSO GET REJECTED DUE TO IT.

Answer (score 36):

#### Android

**Method 1 (all app screens):**

1. Locate your **MainActivity** (*.java* or *.kt*) class inside the embedded android project dir in your Flutter Project,
2. Add the following import to your main activity class:

```
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
```

3. Add the following line to your MainActivity's onCreate method:

```
getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

**Method 2 (for specific screens):**

Use FlutterWindowManagerPlugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager

*Thanks, @Kamlesh!*

Comment: and what about ios?

Comment: Seems there is no real solution for iOS, yet.

Comment: What is path of "MainActivity class" file in flutter? Please suggest.

Comment: For kotlin? MainActivity.kt ?

Comment: @Rebar for iOS maybe https://mrgulshanyadav.medium.com/prevent-screenshot-and-video-recording-in-flutter-93839325d66c

Comment: it records audio when playing video. tested on android 10 & 11

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager

Answer (score 31):

For Flutter2 project

**Method 1** : using package [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager)

**Method 2 :**

**in Android with kotlin**

Step 1 Open the file "mainActivity.kt" using the path

`android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\auth_email\MainActivity.kt`

Step 2 Import Library

```kotlin
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
```

Step 3 In main activity class

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
  }
}
```

**In iOS Swift** : AppDelegate.swift file

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  
  // <Add>
  override func applicationWillResignActive(
    _ application: UIApplication
  ) {
    window?.rootViewController?.view.endEditing(true)
    self.window.isHidden = true;
  }
  override func applicationDidBecomeActive(
    _ application: UIApplication
  ) {
    self.window.isHidden = false;
  }
  

}
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager

Comment: Good news is, now it supports NULL SAFETY also

Comment: what if I want to allow screenshots but want to hide screen on recent tab window ??? for IOS and Android

Comment: for IOS, method 2 also not working.

Comment: @Dharmendra, now we can't disable screenshot in iOS App.

Answer (score 15):

***Updates on July, 2023***:

**I noticed, that Apple started rejecting apps using the hack below. So if you still want to prevent screenshot I think that iOS API parameter [isCaptured](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921651-iscaptured) may be used. I haven't tested it but as an idea you can use Flutter Method Channels to get/set this property.**

On **iOS** I have disabled taking of screenshots with the help of extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/67054892/4899849. Follow next steps:

1. Add property in `AppDelegate`:

   `var field = UITextField()`
2. in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` call next method: `addSecuredView()`

   ```
    private func addSecuredView() {
      if (!window.subviews.contains(field)) {
        window.addSubview(field)
        field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        window.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
        field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(window.layer)
    }
   ```

   }
3. override delegate methods:

   ```
    override func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
      field.isSecureTextEntry = false
    }

    override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
      field.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }
   ```

Now, when you make a screenshot in the app or record a screen video you will see a black image or video. Hope, it will help cuz I spent 2 days trying to make it work)

Full `AppDelegate`:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var field = UITextField()

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

       #if !DEBUG
       addSecuredView()
       #endif
        
       return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    override func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        field.isSecureTextEntry = false
    }

    override func applicationDidBecomeActive(
      _ application: UIApplication
    ) {
        field.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

    private func addSecuredView() {
        if (!window.subviews.contains(field)) {
            window.addSubview(field)
            field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            window.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
            field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(window.layer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your full Appdelegate.swift file?

Comment: @VishnuER updated my answer

Comment: Is there anyway I can upvote this answer multiple times ?

Answer (score 14):

**For Android**:

1. add the flutter package called [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager)  to your
   *pubspec.yaml*
2. import its latest version in pubspec.yaml file of your Flutter project and run pub get. Then add the below code inside the widget's `initState()` method for which you want to disable screenshot and screen recording.

   ```
    Future<void> secureScreen() async {
        await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE); 
     }

     @override
     void initState() {
        secureScreen();
        super.initState();
     }

     @override
     void dispose(){
        super.dispose();
        await FlutterWindowManager.clearFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
     }
   ```

If you want to make your whole app screenshot disable just call `securescreen(`) method (defined above) inside your `main()` function in main.dart file.

**For iOS**:

1. add the flutter plugin called [flutter_prevent_screen_capture](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_prevent_screen_capture) to your
   *pubspec.yaml*

then run flutter pub get.

2. Define variables like below:

```dart
///Define a streamSubscription in order to receive changes
  late StreamSubscription<bool> _screenRecordsSubscription;

  ///Get the instance of plugin for multiple use.
  FlutterPreventScreenCapture preventScreenCapture =
      FlutterPreventScreenCapture();

  ///is Recording is set to false initially.
  bool isRecording = false;
```

3. initialize variables in initstate method:

```dart
updateRecordStatus(bool record) {
   isRecording = record;
   setState(() {});
 }

@override
 void initState() {
   ///Though listening to the screen record, it is recommended to check the screen record status on the first launch.
   checkScreenRecord();

   ///Initialize screenRecordSubscription to regularly listen to the changes
   _screenRecordsSubscription =
       preventScreenCapture.screenRecordsIOS.listen(updateRecordStatus);
   super.initState();
 }
```

So you can listen to the screen recording status.

**If you want to check the screen recording status once:**

```dart
 Future<void> checkScreenRecord() async {
    final recordStatus = await preventScreenCapture.checkScreenRecord();

    debugPrint('Is screen being recorded: $recordStatus');

    isRecording = recordStatus;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

**The last thing is don't forget to cancel subscription in dispose method:**

```dart
@override
  dispose() {
    _screenRecordsSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: I don't acutally know whether it work for IOS but yes it works very well for android.

Comment: @Priyanshjain dear, you forgot to call `clearFlags` in `dispose()` method - `await FlutterWindowManager.clearFlags(
                          FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);` Otherwise it will restrict to take screenshot to all further screens/pages. Please update your answer. Thanks alot.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager

Comment: Works for Android only, No support for iOS

Comment: @Dharmendra Yes it works only for Android

Comment: Currently there's working solution for iOS too.

Answer (score 9):

**What worked for me was writing the below code in MainActivity.java file.**

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
  }
```

and importing these packages!

```
import android.view.WindowManager; 
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.os.Bundle; // required for onCreate parameter
```

Comment: tested using screencapture apps too!

Comment: Why are you repeating the same flat twice?

Answer (score 8):

**Flutter**

**Method 1:** Using this package [screen_protector](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_protector)

**Method 2:**

> In Whole your Application

Open `AppDelegate` file and add `UITextField` variable.

```
private var textField = UITextField()
```

Create a function in `AppDelegate` file.

```
// Screenshot Prevent Functions
    private func makeSecureYourScreen() {
        if (!self.window.subviews.contains(textField)) {
            self.window.addSubview(textField)
            textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.window.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.window.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            self.window.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(textField.layer)
            textField.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.window.layer)
        }
    }
```

Call this method into the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

```
makeSecureYourScreen()
```

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHPCc.png)

---

> In Specific Screen - Using Method Channel

Open `AppDelegate` file and add `UITextField` variable.

```
private var textField = UITextField()
```

Create a function in `AppDelegate` file.

```
// Screenshot Prevent Functions
    private func makeSecureYourScreen() {
        if (!self.window.subviews.contains(textField)) {
            self.window.addSubview(textField)
            textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.window.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.window.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            self.window.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(textField.layer)
            textField.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.window.layer)
        }
    }
```

Call this method into the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

```
makeSecureYourScreen()
```

Also, add your method channel code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

```
let controller : FlutterViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let securityChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "secureScreenshotChannel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        
        securityChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            if call.method == "secureiOS" {
                self.textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
            } else if call.method == "unSecureiOS" {
                self.textField.isSecureTextEntry = false
            }
        })
```

`Add your code below code to your flutter files to disable the screenshot on a specific screen.`

```
// Declare your method channel varibale here
  var iosSecureScreenShotChannel = const MethodChannel('secureScreenshotChannel');
```

Now add code to `initState` to prevent screenshot

```
@override
  void initState() {

    // this method to user can't take screenshots of your application
    iosSecureScreenShotChannel.invokeMethod("secureiOS");

    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
```

For add code to `dispose` to allow screenshots on another screen.

```
@override
  void dispose() {

    // this method to the user can take screenshots of your application
    iosSecureScreenShotChannel.invokeMethod("unSecureiOS");

    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }
```

[Code Screenshot in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XucLX.png)

[Code Screenshot in Flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfCWx.png)

---

You can disable screenshots and video captures like the `Netflix app` and `Disney Hotstar` app.

I have tried it in my application and it works fine.

Answer (score 7):

Screenshots can be prevented very easily by following below two steps.

I am using VS code.

**Step 1** Open the file "mainActivity.kt" using the path `android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\auth_email\MainActivity.kt`

**Step 2** Add the two lines

```
(a) import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams; 

(b) getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE); in MainActivity: FlutterActivity() section
```

**Restart the app**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQHFU.png)

Answer (score 3):

This works for iOS. In your `Runner > AppDelegate.m`:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    self.window.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    self.window.hidden = NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Think twice `AppDelegate.swift` or `AppDelegate.m` ?

Comment: `AppDelegate.m` in case your iOS project is in ObjectiveC. There must be an equivalent for `AppDelegate.swift` in case your iOS project is in Swift :)

Comment: what is the [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
i'm using native ios code

Comment: This does not work when the app is in the foreground.

Comment: could you provide for swift also please

Answer (score 2):

If you are using kotlin

open MainActivity.kt

Add below code at end of imports

```
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams
```

Add below code at end of super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

```
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```

Its done.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

for **android** edit **MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.package.app_name

import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. define this package inside `pubspec.yaml` file

`flutter_windowmanager: ^0.0.1+1`

2. get dependencies

`flutter pub get`

3. You need to call a method of `FlutterWindowManager` using `await` and `async`.
4. You have to add a few lines of code in your `StatefulWidget`.

```
Future<void> secureScreen() async { 
  await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
}

@override 
void initState() {
  secureScreen();
  super.initState(); 
}
```

Comment: This is only going to work for android and not iOS.

Comment: @sagarsuri did you get any solution for iOS.

Comment: @b.john after spending some time I realised that Apple doesn't provide any official API to prevent screenshot capturing or recording. So I have left it out and only implemented it for android.

Answer (score 1):

https://pub.dev/packages/screen_protector

use this one. works for Android, iOS both.
In iOS, screenshot will be captured but output will be black screen.

Comment: But when i am try to take screenshot with simulator not work, have you try to take screenshot or video record using real device work or not?

Comment: @Supriyanto In real device, it worked.

Comment: I just integrated and yeah worked ios and android.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [flutter_windowmanager: ^0.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager/example) package to disable screenshot capture in a Flutter app. To do this, add the following code in your main.dart file:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

> This will add the FLAG_SECURE flag to your app, which will prevent
> screenshots from being captured. Note that this will only work on
> Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe listen for the screenshot keys on iOS and when the combination is being pressed blacken the screen.