# How to prevent screenshots in particular sections of my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

With the help of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317217/flutter-disable-screenshot-capture-for-app) I am able to prevent screenshots in my app but How can I use it only in a particular section of my app. It makes my whole app unshareable.

I have a section that shows notes to my premium members. I don't want the user to take screenshots of it.

My app has MainActivity in kotlin so when I copied the java code from thread mentioned my IDE converted it to Kotlin.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a `MethodChannel` to do that and call the method enabling/disabling screenshots at will.

You can check [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab) for how to do it. The examples calls a method to fetch the battery level, just replace it with your Kotlin method to enable/disable screenshot.

You can then do something like this to pass the argument to decide if it's enable or disable:

```
final platform = MethodChannel("your_channel_name");
platform.invokeMethod('setScreenshotEnableStatus',{'enabled': true})
```

and, from the `MethodCall` object that the `MethodCallHandler` receives, you can recover that argument this way:

```
call.argument('enabled')
```

Another way of doing it is create two native methods, one for enable and one for disable, and call them accordingly.

Another resource for native integration might be [this](https://stablekernel.com/article/flutter-platform-channels-quick-start/), I've quickly skimmed the article and it seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Flutter Package [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager) which was made for this purpose.

> While Android natively supports a range of window modes, there was no good way to set these dynamically within a running Flutter application - instead requiring that these flags are set within the native MainActivity of the Flutter application itself.
>
> In our App, we only wished to disable screenshots for specific screens, rather than across the entire application lifecycle. This can now be accomplished by simply calling:
>
> ```
> await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
> ```
>
> for the relevant screen.
>
> This can further be toggled for a specific screen by either using a RouteAware mixin, or through direct toggling in initState() and dispose() methods in the case of stateful widgets.