# Is there a way to prevent screenshots in IOS using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently working on a project on flutter and I want to disable the user form taking screenshot on the app. I made use of `flutter_windowmanager` package and it worked on android but not on ios, is there a way around the ios part?

Comment: Here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70542897/4899849

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this package
[secure_application](https://pub.dev/packages/secure_application)

### For IOS

The documentation of package says

> Contrary to Android we create a native frosted view over your app content so that content is not visible in the app switcher. When the user gets back to the app we wait for ~500ms to remove this view to allow time for the app to woke and flutter gate to draw

Basically it hides the content on screen by making it Blurr !

Comment: This answer does not in any way answer the question, this package secures the app by blurring when the app is in the background or in the app switcher. It does not prevent screenshots or screen recording.