# How to block screenshot on IOS in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to block screenshot in flutter I have found only one solution everywhere that is to change AppDelegate.m File in the Runner Folder of Flutter  (IOS). But there is no AppDelegate.m File there so that solution is not working for me. Moreover I have tried Screenshot Callback but that also not working because when the Callback is detected the screenshot have been taken. Now I am thinking to run some native code through Flutter Channels for IOS is that possible or is there anyway to prevent screenshot?

Moreover, Can we delete screenshot after taking like we can delete the last picture that been taken after screenshot?

Here is the link to the solution I have described above but not working for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60994901/15415511

Comment: You cannot block screenshots in iOS. There are some commercial solutions that you can license that perform tricky manipulation of the screen in order to render screenshots illegible, but really unless you can remove all of the cameras from the world, blocking screenshots is fairly pointless.

Comment: @Paulw11 Can  you pls share what could be commercial solutions for blocking this on iOS using Flutter?

Comment: @MuhammadAshir Did  you finally achieved this? If yes, how?

Comment: Nope unfortunately not, But I have alert the users upon screenshot and have make a restful API to block users account if he takes more screenshots.