# How to prevent screen recording in Epub Viewer on flutter based application IOS and Android?

Tags: flutter, epub, epub3

How to disabled screen recording for Epub Reader so that user can't take screen shot Or Screen Recording.

Using this Epub Viewer Package:- https://pub.dev/packages/epub_viewer

**Note** :- Already tried flutter_windowmanager but not working on EpubViewer..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: disable screenshot capture for app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317217/flutter-disable-screenshot-capture-for-app)

Comment: No, that is not Working!!