# how can i disable screenshot of a particular screen flutter iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using this package to disable screen in Android [windowManager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager) but does not allow iOS. base on this code

```
 Future<void> secureScreen() async {
    (Platform.isAndroid)
        ? await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE)
        : print('===>iOS');
  }
```

how i want to disable thesame screen on iOs and base on research i was able to found this

```
 override func applicationWillResignActive(
    _ application: UIApplication
  ) {
    self.window.isHidden = true;
  }
  override func applicationDidBecomeActive(
    _ application: UIApplication
  ) {
    self.window.isHidden = false;
  }
```

by adding it to the

> In iOS Swift : AppDelegate.swift file

but this disable the entire app screenshot..

so how can make the swift code active only on a particular screen
thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66997677/12187270 Please check this solution, might be it's helpful for you.

Comment: @NitinGadhiya i have check but still missing somethings like the swift code should be active only on a particular screen..