# Disable screenshots and screen recording on flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, data-security

I am building a learning platform with text, images and video content on **flutter web**. How can I **prevent** screenshots and screen recordings being taken from my site/app?

All the post on the internet are related to Android/iOS. Couldn't find any answers for flutter web.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317217/flutter-disable-screenshot-capture-for-app

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yil6EE2Fivo

Comment: This video is for preventing recording on Android/iOS. Reemphasizing, that i want to disable/prevent it on flutter web

Comment: did you find a solution to prevent screen record on the web yet?

Comment: Did u find any solution?