# Flutter: disable screenshot capture for windows app

Tags: flutter, dart, windows-10

I am making a Flutter app and I need to make sure the user is not able to capture screenshot of the app (any screen). Is there any way to achieve this in Flutter or do I need to write native code for windows 10 any Package or native code can can do it?

flutter applications for windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: disable screenshot capture for app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317217/flutter-disable-screenshot-capture-for-app)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: no this for android and ios but my question for windows