# Flutter Ios prevent screenshot

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I'm blocking screenshots and video records for ios in my app. But when I installed the latest update ios rejected it.

> We noticed that your app shows a custom screenshot-initiated interface
> when the user takes a screenshot, but the interface duplicates the iOS
> system-provided screenshot interface and functionality.
>
> Duplicating system-provided interfaces does not provide the simple,
> innovative, and easy to use experience App Store users expect.

This is rejected message.

This is my code

```
      extension UIWindow {
  func makeSecure() {
      let field = UITextField()
      field.isSecureTextEntry = true
      self.addSubview(field)
      field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
      field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
      self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
      field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.layer)
    }
  }
```

How to I solve it

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem. Apple says that:

"We noticed that your app shows a custom screenshot-initiated interface when the user takes a screenshot, but the interface duplicates the iOS system-provided screenshot interface and functionality.

Specifically, your app only displayed a black blank page when the user takes a screenshot.

Duplicating system-provided interfaces does not provide the simple, innovative, and easy to use experience App Store users expect.

**To resolve this issue, either remove the custom interface or revise it to not duplicate the system-provided screenshot interface and functionality.**"

Comment: custom interface or revise it to not duplicate the system-provided screenshot interface and functionality --- can you please describe more on this?

Comment: @NehilKoshiya I am also getting the same issue. This is causing bcoz of the code block we added to prevent capturing screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Now there's an opportunity to block screen recording in iOS through flutter plugin.

**For iOS**:

1. add the flutter plugin called [flutter_prevent_screen_capture](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_prevent_screen_capture) to your

> *pubspec.yaml*

then run flutter pub get.

2. Define variables like below:

```dart
///Define a streamSubscription in order to receive changes
  late StreamSubscription<bool> _screenRecordsSubscription;

  ///Get the instance of plugin for multiple use.
  FlutterPreventScreenCapture preventScreenCapture =
      FlutterPreventScreenCapture();

  ///is Recording is set to false initially.
  bool isRecording = false;
```

3. initialize variables in initstate method:

```dart
updateRecordStatus(bool record) {
   isRecording = record;
   setState(() {});
 }

@override
 void initState() {
   ///Though listening to the screen record, it is recommended to check the screen record status on the first launch.
   checkScreenRecord();

   ///Initialize screenRecordSubscription to regularly listen to the changes
   _screenRecordsSubscription =
       preventScreenCapture.screenRecordsIOS.listen(updateRecordStatus);
   super.initState();
 }
```

So you can listen to the screen recording status.

**If you want to check the screen recording status once:**

```dart
 Future<void> checkScreenRecord() async {
    final recordStatus = await preventScreenCapture.checkScreenRecord();

    debugPrint('Is screen being recorded: $recordStatus');

    isRecording = recordStatus;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

**The last thing is don't forget to cancel subscription in dispose method:**

```dart
@override
  dispose() {
    _screenRecordsSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```