# I want to detect screen recording in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I want handel when user try screen recording in flutter and close the app

I try write native code but i dont handel screen recording, when user screen recording show black screen in video but i want to habdel this and close the app

Comment: Did you try https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-disable-screenshots/ ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I investigate 'til now, there's no such plugin that helps us prevent capturing or recording our app. Some people might say you should use [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager) but it is only available for Android. Even worse,
I cannot find its source code on pub.dev.

Fortunately, you can modify it easily with native code (Kotlin/Java, Swift/Objective-C). Reference:

- [Flutter: disable screenshot capture for app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317217/flutter-disable-screenshot-capture-for-app)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yaw6PCaEwd4
- https://medium.com/litslink/flutter-preventing-screenshots-and-screen-recording-in-the-app-3e6f55d05ee3