# Disable Screen Capture/Screenshot on flutter multiplateform app

Tags: flutter, macos, security, screen

I have **flutter** app with cross plateform support (Android, ios, windows, macos), ofcourse with Adaptive screens, I need to disable screenshot/screencapture on all platerform to protect content/video on app, I was able to do the same on Android, Ios, want it to be disabled on Macos.

Do anyone have suggestion or method to this?

I can work with native codes also (Java/Kotlin/Swift/C/C++) ofcourse it will be in C/C++ for Macos.

Thanks in Advance!

I have tried to find some C/C++ code to impletent for MacOs
I used screen_protector for Android, Ios.

Answer (score 0):

Update the file `android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/project/MainActivity.kt` as given below!

You need to add a SECURE Flag which restrict to take screenshots, record Screens, and protect from piracy!

```kotlin
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine){
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    }
}
```

Rebuild the app and done!
It won't allow you to take screenshots or screen recordings and will not show the content even on recent apps.

Thanks!

Comment: This code is for android as I said it is cross plateform app to work on mac, windows as well, I am done with android, Ios, windows want the same on MacOs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317217/flutter-disable-screenshot-capture-for-app please give it a try!