# How to disable the Screen-shot in iOS using React-Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am working on POC in which I have to disable screenshot in ios using React-Native

Comment: You cannot. You can at most detect screenshot. Some libraries have done such functionality: https://github.com/blend/react-native-screenshot-detector

Comment: Even if you disable the screenshot, you cannot prohibit taking pictures with another mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Android, in iOS you cannot prevent the user from taking screenshots.

But if you have really have to hide as many as possible information from screenshots, you can try requiring the user to be touching the screen to view whatever information you're displaying (Like Snapchat). This is because the system screenshot event interrupts touches.

Thanks for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680506/4456809) about the idea.