# Disable Screen shots in React-native for IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

In my application I want to disable screen shots function for IOS in React-native.

Please suggest me any working package or any native code which can disable screen shots in IOS.

Comment: You can't disable screen shots in iOS.  Unless you can remove every camera from the world, it would be pointless.,

Comment: The answer was discussed here, check the link.
[check here please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app)