# How can I disable screen iOS capture

Tags: ios, swift, core-foundation

How to disable the screen in iOS or how can we show a blur screen when the screen capture event is trigger? I need to prevent screen capture by users of my app, for security reasons. The contents I display are confidential and should not be copied onto the device.

Comment: 2 words, you cant :| I guess :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent screen capture in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari  please suggest solution, because I tried almost all solution found on google, but not working for me.