# Screenshot Disable For IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, screenshot

How to disable screenshot for a flutter App? I have tried and succeeded in android.
for android :

```
Future<void> secureScreen() async {
    await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
 }
```

just called  securescreen() method (defined above) inside my  main() function in main.dart file.

How can i implement in Ios?

Comment: It's not possible to disable screenshot in iOS

Comment: Is there any other way to obscure screenshot like putting a blur mask or something?

Comment: There are some attempts, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app), however I can’t tell you how to use it on flutter. And in my opinion in most cases the efforts wouldn’t worth it because there’re way too many ways to grab screen data from the device