# Block screenshots in specific app with Intune MDM?

Tags: ios, mdm

Microsoft Endpoint Manager / Intune allows blocking screenshots in general on iOS devices by using iOS's MDM features. This seems to deactivate screenshots completely, for all apps.

What we want to achieve though is blocking screenshots only for our specific app (as part of a BYOD policy) and through iOS's MDM features, not through an API invoked by the app itself and also not by using video-based image manipulation which tends to require third-party paid SDKs (preventing photos taken with other devices is not a priority at the moment).

I found a number of questions e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663448/how-to-block-a-screenshot-in-ios) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app) that all target deactivating screenshots from the app in Swift. They basically say that it is not really possible for non-managed devices or requires some obscure tricks. However I want to achieve this using the iOS MDM configuration options, not from the app itself.

Is there anything I have overlooked regarding app-specific MDM policies around screenshots?

Comment: Intune (or any other MDM) can only deploy a profile containing a restriction that is available on iOS. https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mdm/mdm0f7dd3d8/1/web/1.0  Per-app screenshot blocking is not an available restriction