# iOS: Blocking content in screenshots

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem regarding scammers in my app:

- In the private chat between users, users may feel comfortable sending nudes or other sensitive information
- The other user is a scammer and might screenshot the information and will re-sell it else where or use it to blackmail the user in some capacity.

I can detect screen recordings and if there is an active capturing in progress can hide content

However with screenshots I can only detect the screenshot after the fact but not beforehand to black out content.

Are there any known code patterns or SDKs that assist with this?

Comment: You will never be able to ultimately prevent someone determined to extort information presented to them - they could always just use their phone to take a picture of the screen.

Comment: @Filburt The same is true for all scammer methods, but we try and make it more difficult so that the threshold for entry for these people to do this is harder and higher

Answer (score 2):

**iOS** doesn't allow it, There are no observers for screenshots before being taken. And you can't do anything about it, Because it's just not possible to stop someone from taking screenshots, both physically and digitally. You might want to look into other solutions to protect user data.

Answer (score 0):

The only SDK I know of is [ScreenShieldKit](https://screenshieldkit.com/)

There's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app/67054892#67054892) that provides an alternative, but I've not had a chance to test it out.