# Enable/Disable Screen Capture in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, screen-capture

I am able to disable screen capture in iOS using this code

**Objective- C**

```
- (void)makeSecure {
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        field.secureTextEntry = true;
        [self addSubview:field];
        [[field.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerYAnchor] setActive:YES];
        [[field.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor] setActive:YES];
        [self.layer.superlayer addSublayer:field.layer];
        [field.layer.sublayers.firstObject addSublayer:self.layer];
    }); 
}
```

**Swift**

```
func makeSecure() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.isSecureTextEntry = true
        self.addSubview(field)
        field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
        field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.layer)
    }
}
```

But I am unable to enable the screen capture again.

So is there any way to enable and disable the above code

FYI: [Link used for the above approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: Try hiding or removing the text field. Or toggling `isSecureTextEntry`.