# How to prevent user from taking screenshot or screen recording in iOS 17?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, screenshot, ios17

I have a Flutter app where I want to prevent users from taking screenshots and screen recordings. I have the following code which works perfectly for iOS versions lower than 17 but not for iOS 17.

AppDelegate:

```swift
override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
    
    setUpBlurEffectView()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(toggleScreenBlurForCapture), name: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    window?.makeSecure()
   
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}


func setUpBlurEffectView() {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
    blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView?.frame = window?.bounds ?? UIScreen.main.bounds
    blurEffectView?.isHidden = true
    window?.addSubview(blurEffectView!)
}

@objc func toggleScreenBlurForCapture() {
    let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
    blurEffectView?.isHidden = !isCaptured
}
```

```swift
extension UIWindow {
    func makeSecure() {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.isSecureTextEntry = true
        self.addSubview(field)
        field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
        field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.layer)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Has something changed in iOS 17? Any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Something has changed. The use of a secure text field was always a "hack". It no longer works. If your app is showing video then screen recording can be blocked but otherwise it is not possible. Blocking screenshots and screen recording is pointless while cameras are a thing that exist.

Comment: I also have to block screenshots and screen recording in my app. Please help if you get the answer

Comment: I think the issue is `UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification` not firing the notificaton

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent screen capture in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app)

Answer (score 2):

replace this

```
extension UIWindow {
    func makeSecure() {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.isSecureTextEntry = true
        self.addSubview(field)
        field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
        field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.layer)
    }
}
```

to this

```
extension UIWindow {
    func makeSecure() {
        let field = UITextField()
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: field.frame.self.width, height: field.frame.self.height))
        field.isSecureTextEntry = true
        self.addSubview(field)
        self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
        field.layer.sublayers?.last!.addSublayer(self.layer)
        field.leftView = view
        field.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the above code does?

Comment: Is there a way to then remove this screen protection? make the window insecure again? I tried removing field from its superview, and the removing sublayers, in the order and place it's been added, but after that I keep getting blank black window, and all my UI dissapears

Answer (score 0):

use screen_protector package as it's not possible to prevent the screenshotting on iOS but you can make the user screenshot a black screen instead of your content using the package i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

SUPPORTED IOS 17 AND BELOW VERSIONS

[image]

[Screen Recording in iOS 17.2 device (UIKit, SwiftUI)](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield/blob/main/ScreenShield_ScreenRecording.mov)

I worked on an app where securing chat content was a requirement. After R&D, I concluded that preventing screen capture in an iOS app is not directly supported by the iOS operating system. However, we can customize our code to achieve the desired result.

As a solution, I created [ScreenShield](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield), an iOS library designed to secure content by blocking screenshots and screen recordings. It provides a simple solution to protect your app's content. I hope it proves helpful for others facing the same challenge.

[ScreenShield for ios UIKit/SwiftUI](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield)

HOW TO USE:

Add the following line to your Podfile and run pod install:

```
pod 'ScreenShield'
```

UIKIT EXAMPLE:

```
import UIKit
import ScreenShield

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        
        // Protect ScreenShot
        ScreenShield.shared.protect(view: self.view)
        
        // Protect Screen-Recording
        ScreenShield.shared.protectFromScreenRecording()
    }
}
```

SWIFTUI EXAMPLE:

```
import SwiftUI
import ScreenShield

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .protectScreenshot() // Protect the view
            .onAppear {
                ScreenShield.shared.protectFromScreenRecording() // Protect Screen-Recording
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this library is not working for iOS 17.2 devices.

Comment: @TusharLathiya, I just checked both UIKit and SwiftUI examples in the iOS 17.2 device, It's working fine for me. I updated my answer and shared the [link](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield/blob/main/ScreenShield_ScreenRecording.mov) to screen recording on the iOS 17.2 device.
 Please check and let me share the recording of what exact issue you are facing. Thanks.