# Restrict user on taking screenshot in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, user-controls, screenshot

I want to restrict user to take screenshot in my Xamarin Native iOS application.

I have seen lots of links and code but somehow it does not work for me.

I followed the solution from the link [Restrict user from taking screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app) but when I write this code, I am able to add a UIView layer on screenshot but after that my text filed becomes disable and scroll view also does not work properly.

How to remove that added layer from the Top view.

OnResignActivation and OnActivated won't work as these methods won't get called when screenshot is taken from accessive touch.

Comment: There is no reliable way of preventing screenshots. There is no point in preventing screenshots while cameras are a thing that exist

Answer (score 0):

I've used this approach in an app. It lets the user take screenshots, but the final image has no content.
Haven't noticed any adverse effects on other UI controls.

Add this in AppDelegate.cs,

```
public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
{
    base.OnActivated(application);
    SecureScreenCapture();
}

bool isAntiScreenshotModeEnabled;
private void SecureScreenCapture()
{
    if (isAntiScreenshotModeEnabled)
        return;

    var uiWindow = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ConnectedScenes
                        .OfType<UIWindowScene>()
                        .SelectMany(s => s.Windows)
                        .FirstOrDefault(w => w.IsKeyWindow);

    var textFieldSecured = new UITextField();
    textFieldSecured.SecureTextEntry = true;

    uiWindow.AddSubview(textFieldSecured);
    uiWindow.Layer.SuperLayer?.AddSublayer(textFieldSecured.Layer);
    textFieldSecured.Layer.Sublayers?.Last().AddSublayer(uiWindow.Layer);
    isAntiScreenshotModeEnabled = true;
}
```

The screen capture can again be enabled/disabled by using a reference of the `UITextField` and toggling the `SecureTextEntry`