# Prevent other applications form capturing/recording screen

Tags: android, screen, capture, recording

Basically i want  **VIDEO PIRACY PROTECTION**

My application has video streaming and I want to protect my video streaming from other applications. Other applications should not be able to capture screen while my video is playing. Any suggestions how can i achieve this.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can secure screen capturing functionality by adding FLAG_SECURE into your Activity as follows

```
  getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#UI) link which says

> Screen capturing and sharing
>
> Android 5.0 lets you add screen capturing and screen sharing
>   capabilities to your app with the new android.media.projection APIs.
>   This functionality is useful, for example, if you want to enable
>   screen sharing in a video conferencing app.
>
> The new createVirtualDisplay() method allows your app to capture the
>   contents of the main screen (the default display) into a Surface
>   object, which your app can then send across the network. The API only
>   allows capturing **non-secure screen content**, and not system audio. To
>   begin screen capturing, your app must first request the user’s
>   permission by launching a screen capture dialog using an Intent
>   obtained through the createScreenCaptureIntent() method.

Also documentation at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE)  says that

> Window flag: treat the content of the window as secure, **preventing it
>   from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure
>   displays.**

Above solution will surely prevent applications from capturing Video of your app

Comment: I know this solution works for capturing screen shot. But is it works for video capturing also??

Comment: @Ajay: Either this works or what you want is not supported. So, try it yourself.

Comment: This works fine for video & screenshots. But not able to restrict audio recording. Still audio recorded by other apps.

Comment: @RanjithKumar LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE is for window object only so it can prevent video and screenshots capturing. For restricting audio recording, you have to search for different solution

Comment: Why the h*ll no one mentions where are we supposed to place that line?

Comment: @silwar I  tried using the FLAG and it works fine with most of the screen recorder apps. But [DU Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.DUrecorder.screenrecorder.videorecorde&hl=en_IN&gl=US) somehow manages to record the screen using floating window. Can you help me out?

Comment: @RahulKhurana I will check and let you know if there is any solution for this

Comment: hi @silwar, did you get the time to check?

Comment: hi @RahulKhurana I am going to help you check. Can you send the app (DU Recorder) to me? Preferably the APK file. It seems like it was removed from Google Play.

Answer (score 8):

```
  getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

write above `setContenView();`

It prevents only snapshot capturing. And also prevents video capturing. But For video capturing its device specific.

Comment: Any idea how to prevent video capturing for all devices?

Comment: I am having issues with [DU Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.DUrecorder.screenrecorder.videorecorde&hl=en_IN&gl=US), who somehow manages to record the screen. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this in your `Activity`,

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: I know this solution works for capturing screen shot. But is it works for video capturing also??

Comment: The above code blocks all sort of Screen capture which includes video capture.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have practical experience??

Comment: Read this.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE

Comment: it's audio getting record. I want to mute audio

Comment: u should detect that there is running recroding app, then u can stop displaying your app content