# How do I prevent screen video recording in android application?

Tags: android

I want to prevent my android application from **screen video recorder**.

I tried  this  but this code prevent only screen shot not video recorder.

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following code prevents screen capturing but certainly not to full extent. See the links below.

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE) and these [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6764649/3557080) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30618030/3557080)

Comment: You need to go for root functionalities to enable/disable it

Comment: if we play any video, it will just show blank screen in recording, but audio will get recorded.

Answer (score -1):

In Java you can write above your setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

& in kotlin you can write it as

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```