# React native android: app state when on another activity

Tags: android, react-native

My react application is request for pin when app state change from background to active.
The problem is my application have camera activity and after user take a photo, the app state is change from background to active.

I don't want my app to request pin after user take a photo so i need to detect that going to camera activity is not background state. What i have to do?

Note:
1. it's work well on ios
2. i try [react native AppState has no 'inactive' state on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405533/react-native-appstate-has-no-inactive-state-on-android)
 but it's not work (it might because my application usr react-native-navigation and MainActivity is extend SplashActivity)

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I have a similar issue.

Comment: I solved this problem by add custom state and check it before showing pin

Comment: i kinda ended up doing the same thing... but i made it a bit more generic where i have a custom change listener that fires 5 (4 on android) types of events in stead of the default 3 (2 on android). So that it keeps track of when it goes and comes back from another app and fires "in-other-app" and "back-from-other-app" instead of "background" and "active".

Comment: How do you add custom state ? Can please you show example ?

Comment: @boogie666 Can please you share your solution ?

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies i've added an answer (it's in clojurescript, which is what we use, but it's simple enough to translate to js)

Comment: @boogie666 No change in native android code ?

Comment: for my needs, that was not necessary...

Comment: i forgot some stuff, i've edited my response to include the stuff i forgot about

Comment: Ok thanks for great help

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this was

```
(defn next-state [previous current]
  (case previous
    "in-other-app" (case current
                     "active" "back-from-other-app"
                     "inactive" "in-other-app"
                     "background" "in-other-app")
    "back-from-other-app" current
    current))

(def previous-state-atom (atom (.-currentState app-state)))
(defn add-app-state-listener [f]
  (.addEventListener app-state "change"
    (fn [state]
      (let [current-state (next-state @previous-state-atom state)]
        (f current-state)
        (reset! previous-state-atom current-state)))))
```

Basically i keep track of what the previous state was and used that and the next state to fire a custom event (i.e. trigger a function with a string a the event)

Hope this helps somebody...

Edit:

i forgot about this:

```
(defn mark-open-other-app!
  "!!!MUST CALL!!! before any call that results in the opening of another app
  like ImagePicker/showImagePicker or c/open-link."
  []
  (when (= :android (di/device))
    (reset! previous-state-atom "in-other-app")))
```

to set the correct state when going into another app.

```
(defn cancel-open-other-app!
  "Api's like ImagePicker/showImagePicker can be cancelled in which case this function must be called to reset the app state"
  []
  (when (= :android (di/device))
    (reset! previous-state-atom "active")))
```

and this one to setup stuff back when you cancel.