# React native: how to prevent screen record on android?

Tags: android, react-native

After I have researched most of the answer to prevent screen record is

```
import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }
}
```

but this does not actually work for me and don't really get into develop android app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406316/5908974

Comment: I have done on newly create project followed the link but I got an error F:\ReactNative\testVideoCapture\android\app\src\main\java\com\testvideocapture\MainApplication.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    ^
  symbol:   method getWindow()
  location: class MainApplication
1 error
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

do you have any working example on react native?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/hawkup/react-native-prevent-screenshot) here is working example tested on android