# How to disallow screenshoot in ionic 3?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

How can I prevent the user from taking screenshots in ionic 3? I can not find any info about how to disallow take screenshots on android using ionic 3 for example using ionic native.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406316/1306012
But why do you want to do that? If someone wants to take a screenshot of your app this person could simply take a photo of the smartphone with another phone. I don't see the point doing this. Maybe explaining what's your goal would help the question to get answers which brings something to you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at this - "PrivacyScreenPlugin" at "https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-privacyscreen"?

I used the same to disable screenshots for my Android App and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following links:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/168/how-to-disable-screenshots-within-a-cordova-application-in-android

Comment: Rather than linking to external URL, please add relevant code and explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Command.

1. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-privacyscreen
2. npm i cordova-plugin-privacyscreen

I hope this is help you.