# How to disabled screenshoots in react-native app?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I have made a mobile app using react-native (only android for now and it is not an expo app) and I would like to forbid users to take screenshots while the app is open. I know it is impossible to disable this completely but I would like to make it at least more difficult to take screenshots. There are some examples I found but I don't how to implement them for example:

[How to prevent Screen Capture in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android)

I tried to put:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

in my `app_name/android/app/src/main/java/com/app_name/MainApplication.java` file, in the `onCreate()` method and then I can't compile the app to see if it works. The same is when I tried to create a class like in this:

[How do I prevent Android taking a screenshot when my app goes to the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background)

There are some npm-s for this issue but I had also no success in installing/using them.

Does anyone know how to set a flag so the users of my react-native (android) app can't take screenshots while using the app?

The error I get when add: `getWindow().setFlags` and then press `Build` in android-studio is:

> error: package WindowManager does not exist

and I also tried to this package:

```
yarn add react-native-anti-screenshot
yarn add v1.7.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-native-anti-screenshot: Not found".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/mislav/workspace2/umye/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Looks like there is no easy solution to disable screenshots or did i miss something?

I'm pretty new in developing mobile apps so please if you can help me explain it as simple as you can.

Thank you!

Comment: Set it in `MainActivity.java` instead of `MainApplication.java`

Comment: Please elaborate these sentences more `I can't compile the app`.. Why you can't compile? What is the error? `I had also no success in installing/using them`... What exact issue did you face?

Answer (score -1):

try this code in MainActivity.java file:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
    {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    };

 }
```