# Prevent screenrecording on Expo React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo SDK `31.0.0`

On Android, I can disable screen recording by setting the `FLAG_SECURE` flag.
Is there a way to do the eqivalent in iOS?

https://github.com/hawkup/react-native-prevent-screenshot

[How to disabled screenshoots in react-native app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382104/how-to-disabled-screenshoots-in-react-native-app?rq=1)

Seem to be solutions that work on an ejected app.

How can I achieve this using Expo? I do not want to eject the app.