# How can i restrict my Application being Screen Shared?

Tags: android, screensharing, screencast

How can I achieve this programmatically?

Screen sharing-Screen sharing feasibility in Application needs to be disabled, the user will not be allowed to share the screen or give remote access of the application via using any third-party app.

Comment: Did you check out `FLAG_SECURE`? 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE

Comment: I want to do it Application Wide.

Comment: Create a `BaseActivity` with `FLAG_SECURE` and extends all other Activities from it . This is the only way i can think of.

Comment: Thanks. I had BaseActivity and all i have to do is add this before setcontentview - getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

Answer (score 1):

We cannot completely avoid screen sharing. FLAG_SECURE is a way to avoid screen capture or video capture. Have a look at this answer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406316/5453659)