# Android Device Screenshot, Screen Recording disable

Tags: android

Disabling or blur the screen while taking screenshot or screen recording while my app is running in background on device level, beyond application. This there a way to achieve this?

I tried `MDM` to achieve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Screen Capture in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android

Comment: i want restrict screen capture and screen recording outside my app.

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```