# Implementing custom watermark text over a video player widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to implement dynamic watermarking feature in my flutter app to show "logged-in user id" as watermark-text over the video player which should change it's position while the video is playing.

I'm thinking of using flutter's [overlay_container](https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_container) somehow to do this. but I'm still unsure.

How can I implement such feature? is there any better approach or flutter widget that might help me in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a stack which the video and the text are positioned items?

Comment: @TinusJackson will I be able to change the watermark text position over the video while it's playing? the whole thing is to prevent a user to screen-record the videos.

Comment: this might be more what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406316/4712391

Comment: Oh, really thanks for this link. this will indeed be helpful. but there's a corner case where a user might do screen record on pc using bluestacks android emulator and then using any pc screen capture software. I want this watermark feature as an extra layer of added security. this will help discourage the user from using screen recording. @TinusJackson

Comment: is there any other way to avoid this kind of screen capturing using pc?