# How to prevent android apps from screen-recording my android system

Tags: android, security, screenshot, microsoft-teams, video-recording

While using Microsoft teams application on android, I decided to record the lecture using a screen recording application built-in within the system.

The screen recording application says that there is another screen recording application is running (see screenshot below). I closed teams and started my screen recording again and it worked!!.

Many other applications that provide a random video call with strangers also have the same problem.

So, my questions are:

- How to prevent any application from recording my android screen?
- How to let android tell me about any applications that record my screen?
- Are these applications spying on me?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PoZf.png)

EDIT:
I have checked other questions similar to this issue, but all is about using SECURE flag in the application code. Clearly, I want to prevent any application downloaded from Google Play to record my android screen.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android this link ?

Answer (score 0):

try this
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

Comment: I am not asking about a certain application I develop, but applications, like teams, are recording my screen.