# Protect view (from all accessibility services, spyware and similar)

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

How can I protect views and their content from any accessibility service and maybe other ways spyware could read my apps data from the screen? Like banking apps (should) do it e.g.?

**Background**

I want to write a small open source and *minimal* password manager where you can just enter your sensitive data and read it, if desired and needed.

**What I found so far is following**

- I can set the [IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS) flag in my root view, this should save my app from accessibility services

**Questions**

- does the flag above reliably protect my app from any accessibility service?
- banking apps often disallow screenshots - how can I do this as well?
- anything else that I should block to protect my app?

Comment: Did you not find: [How to prevent Screen Capture in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28606689/295004)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822607/115145