# Is there a configuration on manifest level to prevent screenshots/screen recordings in an android app?

Tags: android, android-manifest, screenshot

My SDK uses several dependencies that use their own activities. Some of them allow me to configure the screenshot protection level (allow or not), other never allows them, and a third one doesn´t have any way to configure it. If I set my SDK to not allow screenshots (and cascade that to the dependency that allows me to set that configuration), there´s still a screen (belonging to the third dependency, the one without this feature) that can be fully seen.

Yes, the third dependency would need to develop this feature, but at the moment I'm looking for a way to set this protection level regardless which activity is shown. Is there a way, maybe setting something on the manifest, to get this?

I know that programmatically it would be

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

but I have no access to the dependency´s activity to apply this, hence looking for an alternative.

Comment: You can create a Application class and use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and on activity creation you use secure flags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56524964/7877442 this might help you

Comment: Looks good, but is there an equivalent class to Application that works for SDKs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, for an SDK/Library there´s no way to enforce a security policy like on Activities belonging to third party dependencies unless said dependencies have a feature like the one mentioned on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SECURE) about it :

but at the end , you cant 100% be sure about that