# Cannot secure window on Android 12 with WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

On Android 12, if I create an simple app with `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
        )
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

the window does not secure if I try to switch apps

[image]

however, if I switch back, the window does secure

[image]

In both cases, switching to or from, the window secures on Android 11, but not on Android 12. Any idea why?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android Hope this helps.

Comment: Also have a look at my question too. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651691/4134215

Answer (score 4):

Easy approach using `View#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)` on your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  if (hasFocus) {
    // allow screenshots when activity is focused
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
  } else {
    // hide information (blank view) on app switcher
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
  }
}
```

Comment: If Any Modal components render than hasFocus returns false. but actually App is in foreground only

Comment: @Aure77 Also see my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651691/4134215

Answer (score 3):

As of Android version 12, it was the desired behavior. additionally, you can check the Google Issue Tracker.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237190495

> Instead of onPause and onResume, we can use
> onWindowFocusChanged(boolean).when the activity does not have focus we
> can enable FLAG_SECURE when the app does regain focus we can clear
> FLAG_SECURE

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
       if (hasFocus) {
             window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
          } else {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A new flag is added in Android 13 to prevent the app preview from appearing in the Recent Apps.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setRecentsScreenshotEnabled(boolean)
Although this is not for Android 12, I am sharing here for people who are interested in this feature.