I can't make screenshot protection on android studio
I added FLAG_SECURE to my project to protect against screenshots, but it doesn't work, I tried it on a simple project, but it didn't work there either. What to do?
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

I tried to run on 3 different projects, as well as on other devices with different versions of android, but without success

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72120552/150978

use FLAG_SECURE code after the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  for example
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
