# How to hide the app from screenshots and screen recordings, without leaving blank rectangle?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, screenshot, android-windowmanager

I want to hide my app (which has also floating services views) from screenshots and screen recordings, I tried with the following tag:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
```

It hides the app from the screen recording but shows a black rectangle on the service view, so I wonder what could be the approach to hide the app and services view from this recording without leaving a blank black rectangle?

Comment: Already answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406316/6816307)

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible. Besides... what would you expect to be shown there instead?

Comment: @CommonsWare I was expecting to make the app totally transparent as it is not there in the screen recording