# How to prevent screen capture in Godot?

Tags: screenshot, godot, screen-recording

Is there a way to prevent screen capture of an android app made with Godot? I have an unfinished project and I want to use it to freelance but I don't want the client/employer that sees my work to steal it by taking screenshots or making screen records of the app and sending them to a programmer to remake the app and put on play store even before I can finish it. Is there a way I can disable screen capturing of the app so that when anyone takes a screenshot, the image will be black?

Comment: In all honesty, I think you need legal advice, not this.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply but what kind of legal advice? Also, I still want to know how, for future purposes. So do you have an idea of how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but at least this comes to mind: register your work with your government, and have legal wording on your contract and the license under you give the work to them so you retain rights on the work. - By the way, they can always take a photo of the screen of the mobile device with another one, and that is without going into more sophisticated workarounds. Edit: As per how to do it, I believe it can be done with permission flag on the application installation. I don't know how do it with Godot.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the advice. I'll see to that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent screen capture in Android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764568/prevent-screen-capture-in-android-apps)